# Best practice for verifying uniqueness in database?

Tags: mysql, unique

I'm creating a database which requires several fields to be unique, and was wondering which method is *least expensive* in terms of checking that uniqueness?

1. Query the database with a mysqli() call to check if a value exists?
2. Use PHP to download a file of all entries, then check that file and delete afterwards
3. Set columns to "Unique" index

If the best option (which I'm assuming it is) is to set the columns to unique, then how do you go about handling the error that gets thrown when the value already exists without breaking out of the function? Or is that even possible?

Comment: third option is the best practice. after getting error form mysql have an exception in your application to handle it

Comment: On any database of non-trivial size, "all" is presumed to be infinite and can't ever be used as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Querying the database first risks [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). That is, you SELECT to verify the value isn't already there, so you can INSERT it. But unfortunately, in the brief moment between your SELECT and your INSERT, someone else slips in and inserts the value you were going to add. So you end up having to catch the error anyway.

   This may seem unlikely, but there's some old wisdom: ["one in a million is next Tuesday."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx) I.e. when we process millions of transactions per day, even a rare fluke is bound to happen sooner than we think.
2. This is right out. What happens when the set of entries is 10 million long? 100 million? 1 billion?  This solution doesn't scale, so just put it out of your mind immediately.
3. Yes, use a UNIQUE constraint.  Attempt the INSERT and handle the error. This avoids a race condition, because your INSERT's unique check is atomic. That is, no one can slip in between the clock ticks to add a value before you can insert it.

   One caveat of this: in MySQL's InnoDB storage engine, if you try an INSERT and it fails due to conflicting with a UNIQUE constraint (or other reason for failure), [it doesn't reverse its allocation of the next auto-increment value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html). The row is not inserted, but the auto-inc value is generated and discarded. So if you have frequent cases of such failures, you could end up skipping a lot of integers in your primary key. I had one case where my customer actually ran out of integers because they were skipping 1500 id values for each row that was successfully inserted. In their case, I suggested using your solution 1, then try the insert only if they are "pretty sure" of a safe insert, but then they have to handle the error anyway just in case of the race condition.

   Handling the error means checking the return value **every time you execute an SQL query**. I can't tell you how many questions I read on StackOverflow where programmers fail to check that execute() returned `false`, and they wonder why their INSERT failed.

Comment: PDO configured with exceptions turned on makes it very hard to miss errors. Not sure if `mysqli` has a similar facility.

Comment: @tadman, yes, it does: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Comment: Very well worded, sir. I'm not sure if this project will ever get to the tens of millions scale, but I am anticipating it to be in the hundreds of thousands. I hadn't even thought of your first scenario about race conditions.

Comment: So in regards to the combining method 1 and 3 to work in conjunction with each other, is there a significant resource usage difference versus using only method 3 and crossing my fingers that I don't have the same experience your client did?

Comment: It should be a very quick SELECT, because you're looking up a specific value in a unique index. MySQL is very good at that. And if it does find a conflict, then don't do the INSERT at all.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is let the database do it if at all possible.

The slower answer depends on how you want to handle exceptions to your uniqueness requirement.

If you never need to over-ride the uniqueness requirement, you can use a UNIQUE index in MySQL. Then you can use "ON DUPLICATE KEY" to handle the exceptions.

However, if you sometimes need to allow a duplicate, you can't use a UNIQUE key and you'd be best using a regular INDEX and doing a query first to see if the value exists before you insert it.

Comment: Didn't even think of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`... It's amazing how the simple things can slip our minds when we're tunnel-visioned on one thing at a time. lol

Answer (score 1):

Well, the least expensive is one point, the user experience is another.

I would personnaly go for a query (with a custom message if key is found) AND a Unique constraint (to have a consistent db). So 1 + 3.

But if you want less expensive, just go to the unique constraint, and try to build some comprehensive error message, using the error message from `mysqli_error`.

So 1 + 3 or 3, but not 2.

Comment: I'm anticipating this project to get fairly beefy, so I'm definitely in the market for the speediest interactions possible. So it looks like 3 it is.